# While Executing Procedure with multiple out parameter getting an error 'Input String was not in a correct format'

Tags: c#, mysql

```
            MyCmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT FnGetTransDate()", MyCon);
            MyCon.Open();
            MyRead = MyCmd.ExecuteReader();
            MyRead.Read();
            transdate = Convert.ToDateTime(MyRead.GetValue(0).ToString());
            MyRead.Close();
            MyCmd = new MySqlCommand("SpGenProcess", MyCon);
            MyCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tempprocessidlist", idlist);
            MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prdate",Convert.ToDateTime(transdate.ToShortDateString()));
            MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out_status", MySqlDbType.Int32);
            MyCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@out_msg", MySqlDbType.VarChar);
            MyCmd.Parameters["@out_status"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            MyCmd.Parameters["@out_msg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            int.TryParse(MyCmd.Parameters["@out_status"].Value.ToString(), out outstatus);
            ErMsg = MyCmd.Parameters["@out_msg"].Value.ToString();
```

While Executing the statement 'MyCMd.ExecuteNonQuery()' getting error Inupt string was not in correct format ?? [Error On Line ExecuteNonQuery]

Comment: which line, please show the line

Comment: Can you give us the trace? Show all your errors to us!

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecuteReader` if you need to read the values from the reader

```
var reader = MyCmd.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        int status  = (int)reader["out_status"];//breakpoint here
        string msg = (string)reader["out_msg"]; //here also
    }
}
```